# What material should I used for a plastic encapsulated ASIC in a thermal simulation?

Tags: thermal

I'm working on a project to improve the thermal performance of one of our boards. And I'm playing around with Fusion 360's new electronic cooling simulator. I'm not sure what material to assign to the ASIC I want to look at it. It's just a standard plastic package (I assume it's CNE) but there's not CNE in Fusion. What do people usually do for this?  Choose another plastic, or make a custom material?

Thanks!

Comment: Epoxy basically

Comment: Yes CNE specifically, but I'm wondering what people assign in simulation.